# Why I can't save and preview photo

Tags: ios

If i comment the code for saving photo, i can preview the photo and if i comment the code for preview photo, i can save the photo to the camera roll

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Testing" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    photoPreview.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're commenting one out of course it isn't going to work. You have to merge the methods.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    photoPreview.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Testing" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```